# why private int d cannot be written in maxPath() , but before the diameterOfBinaryTree()

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    private int d;
    public int diameterOfBinaryTree(TreeNode root) {
        d = 0;
        maxPath(root);
        return d ;
    }
    private int maxPath (TreeNode node){
        
        if (node == null) {return 0;}
        int leftDepth = maxPath(node.left);
        int rightDepth= maxPath(node.right);
       // d = Math.max(d,leftDepth + rightDepth );

        if (d < leftDepth + rightDepth) {d = leftDepth + rightDepth;}
        
        return Math.max(leftDepth, rightDepth) +1;     
        
    }
}
```

on the second line, why the "private int d" has to be written before the diameterOfBinaryTree()???? and can I set it as public ??

Comment: 1)  Because `private` can only be used for fields.  It doesn't make sense to put an access modifier (`private`, `public`, `protected`) on a >local< variable, because local variables cannot be accessed outside of the method anyway.  They are not in scope for any code outside of the method. 2) You can set a field top be `public` but it is inadvisable ...

Comment: Generally ask yourself: does this instance variable need to be public? If the answer isn't  definite "yes!", then it should probably be private.

Comment: ``d`` needs to be an instance variable because you are sharing it between two methods. You could rewrite your code to pass the value as a parameter and receive the new value as a return value.

Answer (score 1):

`private`, `public` and `protected` modifiers apply to members, not local variables (that aren't accessible outside the scope they were defined in anyway).

You can make `d` `public` if you want it to be accessible from other classes and not just internally from `Solution`'s methods.